# Apex cpu time limit without change anything

Tags: apex, time, cpu

In my instance I could insert or update record with a batch size of 100 records without problem.

The last week and **with the same code in production** we started to get the apex cpu limit and we have to reduce the batch size to 10!!

Even the **test classes** in production started to fail. The same classes that worked perfect days before. How is this possible??

I think it's very strange. Salesforce does not give any explication and only send information about this limit. I know why this limit occurs but dont understand that, one day works fine and suddenly everything start to fail...

Anyone had had something similar?

Comment: An instance can slow down and have issues. Have you gone to trust.salesforce.com to check and see if your instance was having problems?

Comment: Could it be like someone added a new workflow that may update records so new triggers execute and use more cpu time. So now only inserts/updates of small chunks are avaiable. And same applies for test classes. 

PD: Deleted my other comments since I understood initially you were talking about a Apex Batch, not about chunks of records.  

Check if you have workflows or triggers that may interact with each other.

Comment: Yes, I always go to trust.salesforce.com but always it's green. We think It's something related with the summer 16 but who knows..

Comment: Are the test classes using `seeAllData=true`? If so, there may be a data problem.

Comment: No, we never use this option.

Comment: Alex, yes batchsize maybe it's confusing.. It's just a chunk of records in a trigger..And yes no workflows has been added...

Comment: The answer was easy. Salesforce started to apply this limit. I don't know why but during more than one year, Salesforce doesn't count this limit in my org. But suddlenly start to apply it. So, I had to improve the code ;-)